# What's the shortcut to go to a class' method in Eclipse on a Mac?

Tags: java, eclipse

Say I have this class, with a simple method.

```
public class Constant {
    ...

    public static int onePlusOne() {
        return 2;
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in another class, I do the following:

```
public class Calculator {
    ...
    public int calculate() {
        return Constant.onePlusOne();
    }
}
```

In AndroidStudio, if I hover to onePlusOne() in Calculator class, then press `cmd + b`, then it will open Constant class, with the cursor right on the `onePlusOne()` method.

How do we do this in Eclipse?

Comment: just hit `ctrl+click on method name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hover to onePlusOne() in Calculator class, then press `CTRL+ Click` the method.
Or Press <kbd>F3</kbd>

Comment: On a Mac, it's `fn + f3`

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, just hold down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and click on the method name, or put the cursor somewhere in the method call and press <kbd>F3</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

right click on the method and then "Open Declaration"

Answer (score 0):

**Windows** 
press and hold ctrl button and click on
     oneplusone();

**Mac**
press and hold command button and click on oneplusone();